# Connecting to An External (outside of Google Cloud Platform) PostgreSQL db from Google Cloud Run

Tags: r, postgresql, docker, google-cloud-run

I've been going around in circles trying to look for information on this, and all I find is connecting to Google Cloud SQL from Google Cloud Run - this is not what I want.

I have a PostgreSQL database installed on a server, outside of GCP. I have a R Shiny app, being deployed as a docker container thru Google Cloud Run, that needs access to the PostgreSQL database that lives outside of GCP.

When I run my R Shiny docker container on my local machine, using docker desktop, it works fine. The connection is made and I see no errors. I logged into my postgresql db directly with the username/password and I also could log in, no problem.

When I run my R Shiny docker container in Google Cloud Run, I get the following errors:

```
Warning: Error in postgresqlNewConnection: RS-DBI driver: (could not connect xxxx@xxpostgresxx.client.ext:5432 on dbname "db_name": could not translate host name "xxpostgresxx.client.ext" to address: Name or service not known
```

In my *.R file, the connection is written like this:

```
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
  con <- dbConnect(drv, host = "xxx.xxx.ext", port = "5432", dbname = "db_name", user = "xxxx", password = "xxxx")
```

Is this an issue with my external PostgreSQL db not allowing the Google Cloud Run url to access it's database? Is it something with the "RS-DBI driver" itself? Or is there something I need to setup somewhere in GCP to get this connection to work?

I've tried pulling in the DBI library before the RPostgreSQL library (someone mentioned it) but that didn't solve anything.

I am a newbie with Google Cloud Platform, so you'll probably have to give more detail in your explanations. Thank you so much in advance.

=====================================

UPDATE:

So in order to make this work, I had to set up a "Serverless VPC access" without networking people to allow my Cloud Run service to connect to resources within our private VPN network.

Comment: Could you try using the public IP address of your postgr instance as mentioned by DazWilkin?

Comment: Do you have any filter in front of your database? IP allowlist, FQDN allowlist,... How do you authorize, or block, some external connections to your database?

Comment: @RJC, I may have to try this, yes. It could be due to a network issue.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, this i don't know. I've asked my manager who I should talk to about looking into this. maybe its just a matter of adding the url of the app to the "allow" list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Run needs a public IP or DNS name by which to locate your Postgres database; it appears to be having problems using `xxx.xxx.ext`.

I'm unfamiliar with `.ext`. Is that a legitimate public Internet DNS name? If not, that's your (first) problem.

Corrollary: could any other entity on the Internet, use a Postgres client and suitable credentials connect to that Postgres database?

Comment: it never occurred to me that *.ext is not a normal public DNS name. We have a few postgresql servers, and all have the *.ext extension. Now that you mention it, all the projects that I know that connect to the postgresql dbs have been within our VPN. ok, lightbulb is going on. thanks!